My Account Page not wok from unexpecting reason.. (404 error)
perma links…
can you help me with this..
on user customer login (myaccpage dont work)
See the video (1st is Customer login / 2nd is admin login): https://youtu.be/mi3ANkb4Qj0
Also in from admin permision its show my account page.. but dont open any single detail.. orders/edit adress.. etc
Also can you check my website permalinks.. becouse when i have like this settings in permalink controlpanel https://imgur.com/a/4yQsVpO – Single product page is open… but Category isnt.. like this: https://imgur.com/a/viuKVLW
But when i setup like this : https://imgur.com/a/AstKHLZ – Single product is 404 – But Category page work… but Single page show same 404 error…
Its work normaly am not install aditional plugins or something..

https://imgur.com/a/SJTWqn3 its working

https://anitaobuca.rs/moj-nalog/edit-account/
